# This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, qlikview

I am trying to render google maps with the following link inside QlikView application

- http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=23.01,84.49&zoom=5&maptype=roadmap&size=640x400&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&.jpg
- (I have created a BROWSER API key)

The error message I am getting is (not in QlikView, but in browser, when I try to render the link using browser):

- The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This site or IP is not authorized to use this API key.

I have actvated following Google services on my account:

- Google Maps Android API v2
- Google Maps JavaScript API v3
- Static Maps API
- Translate API

Already found this thread on StackOverflow: [The Google Maps API server rejected your request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408066/the-google-maps-api-server-rejected-your-request)

I have tried the following:

- make sure the Referers is set to Any referer allowed
- Make sure you have enabled "Static Maps API" service in addition to "Google Maps API".

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error message.
Can anyone help please? Thanks.

Comment: Do you actually have a **valid** key?

Comment: You can always try to generate a new key, if that is an option.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: how can I check it?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: tried it already...

Comment: How does your *Referers* look like?

Comment: @MrUpsidown: "Key for browser apps (with referers) -> Referrers: Any referer allowed"

Comment: So you just have a *star* (*), right?

Comment: "Accept requests from these HTTP referers (web sites):" I have tried with and without star - same error msg

Comment: Strange. From your wording I assume you are using the *old* console. Have you eventually tried with the new console? https://console.developers.google.com/project No idea why that would change anything, but who knows...

Comment: @MrUpsidown: I have tried it also with a new console

Comment: I am almost out of ideas. Double check the key, regenerate, empty your browser cache, clear any cache in QlikView (?), double check the output HTML...

Comment: This thing is driving me crazy... I have tried it with another key using my other Google Account, and it's still not working.
I am testing it from my company's intranet. Does that have any influence?

Comment: Have you allowed your site in the "Edit allowed referrers" section (see  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial )? Doing this in a corporate environment brings a host of other possibilities. I'd make sure that the site is in the trusted or intranet sites zone, since if not, it's possible that something in Group Policy is blocking.

Answer (score 1):

generate key from https://console.developers.google.com/ for maps api of type browser key. And make sure that while calling `document.referrer` should be set to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Google API keys are binded to Domain Names, if you request a Google Service from a site that is not whitelisted the request gets tossed.

Go to your Google Console. https://console.developers.google.com/
Click in the left Menu `API's & Auth` then `Credential`

Under `Public API access` click `create new key` and choose on the next Page `Browser Key`. You are now forced to enter all Domain Names that are allowed to make API request with this key.

Enter your Domain names use the new key and you should ready to go.