# Google Map API rejected request

Tags: api, google-maps, google-api

Having issues with my map that I put on my webpage. When I view the code and site on my local machine, I see it with no issue. Once I upload it to the server it comes back with:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.

```
 <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyCZQwKWv_dRfa94F8mxRiOU7D6LAnYfUoE&q=346+E+Church+Rd,+King+of+Prussia,+PA+19406" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

In google's API authorization area "credentials" I have the referrer set to *.domainname.com/*

Not sure what the issue is...any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408066/the-google-maps-api-server-rejected-your-request

Comment: jbutler483, I looked at that one, didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled the service Static Maps API?

Comment: Scratch that. It now appears to be functioning. Thanks for the help!