# Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL Google maps api URL

Tags: java, swing, google-maps

I'm working on a program that is supposed to display a map with java swing using a google maps api url by given coordinates, my problem is that when i run the code i get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL
```

This is my code

```
public class GoogleMapsDem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame test = new JFrame("Google Maps");

        try {
            String latitude = "40.714728";
            String longitude = "-73.998672";

            String imageUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
                    latitude +
                    "," +
                    longitude +
                    "&zoom=11&size=612x612&scale=2&maptype=roadmap&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
            String destinationFile = "image.jpg";

            // read the map image from Google
            // then save it to a local file: image.jpg
            //
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

            byte[] b = new byte[2048];
            int length;

            while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, length);
            }

            is.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        // create a GUI component that loads the image: image.jpg
        //
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon((new ImageIcon("image.jpg"))
                .getImage().getScaledInstance(630, 600,
                        java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        test.add(new JLabel(imageIcon));

        // show the GUI window
        test.setVisible(true);
        test.pack();
    }
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Make sure you have enabled "Static Maps API" service in addition to "Google Maps API". 
                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408066/the-google-maps-api-server-rejected-your-request

Comment: It looks like you've included your google maps API key – you may want to reset that, since it's now public and bad actors may steal it.

Answer (score 1):

The status code 403 Forbidden represents a client error, which means that the server has the ability to process the request but refuses to authorize access. Simply put, you do not have permission to access this url